# HTML form complete two actions? Verify then redirect through one submit button

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal, action

I'm having trouble integrating the paypal form into my order page.

My order page currently already has a form that the user fills out, and a submit button:

```
<form id="order-form" form name="orderform" method="post" action="send_order_email.php">
```

This send_order_email.php goes through and validates whether the form is valid or not, if not it redirects to a sorry page if valid I would like it to redirect to paypal with the below:

```
 <form target=paypal action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method=post>
    <input type=image src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif " border=0 name=submit alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <input type=hidden name=add value=1>
    <input type=hidden name=cmd value=_cart>
    <input type=hidden name=business value=" info@info.co.uk">
    <input type=hidden name=item_name value="item">
</form>
```

At the moment I can only get either the form to send by making the `action="send_order_email.php"` or I can make the form redirect to paypal by making the `form target=paypal action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"`, this however doesn't go through any of the validation and sends no emails.

How can I get the form to do both actions - Verify one form and then redirect using paypals submit form all through one submit button?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use JavaScript to validate. If that's not a suitable solution (and you want to validate server-side anyway), validate in the PHP script and then redirect to PayPal within the script itself once validations have completed.

Comment: Something like this at the end of your validation script: `header( 'Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );`

Comment: Use ajax for first form and on success triger paypal submit button

Comment: 1) agree with all others that Ajax or even simple java-script would be a better option. 2) if you don't feel like re writing your validation script in JS, the method arensb proposed re: construct an HTTP POST reuest with the various fields would work, since this is just a STANDARD PAYMENT add to cart button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After send_order_email has verified it's correct, just generate a html page with the form you posted (the one with hidden fields), populate it with the data you've received and autosubmit it using javascript, i.e.

```
<body onload="document.theform.submit()">
   <form target=paypal action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method=post name="theform">
    <input type=image src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif " border=0 name=submit alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <input type=hidden name=add value=1>
    <input type=hidden name=cmd value=_cart>
    <input type=hidden name=business value=" info@info.co.uk">
    <input type=hidden name=item_name value="item">
</form>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use POST, or rather, if PayPal requires POST, then I don't think you can redirect. Not in the sense of returning a `Location: http://www.paypal.com/foo/bar` HTTP header, anyway.

You can have `send_order_email.php` take the information provided by the user, and submit it to PayPal. That is, your PHP code can construct an HTTP POST request with the various fields, then send it off to www.paypal.com and process the result. But I doubt that'll work, because PayPayl will probably ask for a credit card number or PIN that you shouldn't have.

As BoydP said above, if you can do validation on the client in JavaScript, great. But if you want to (or need to) do validation on the server, in PHP, then the best approach might be to use two screens: in the first, the user fills in information. In the second, the page displays the information and asks the user to confirm the transaction, using the `<form>` code you pasted above.